# How to access controls inside an XML object/control using C#/ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, xml

I'm new to XML/XSLT. What I did is I've created an XML file with some list, and used XSLT to transform it.

Here's the code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.form1.Controls.Add(Xml1);

    Button btnSubmit = new Button();
    btnSubmit.Text = "Submit";
    this.form1.Controls.Add(btnSubmit);
    btnSubmit.Click += new System.EventHandler(btnSubmit_Click);

    Xml1.DocumentSource = "~/xml/XML_F52E2B61-18A1-11d1-B105-00805F49916B1.xml";
    Xml1.TransformSource = "~/KPI_table.xslt";

    //Together, the Xml1.DocumentSource and the Xml1.TransformSource will display a 
    //list of items with a dropdownlist each.
}

private void btnSubmit_Click(Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (Control c in form1.Controls) //or is it possible to access the controls
                                          //inside XML1 here?
    {
         //This is where I need to access the controls inside the Xml1 object.
    }
}
```

When I tried to debug/trace the program, I found out that the foreach loop only saw 3 controls (`System.Web.UI.LiteralControl`, `System.Web.UI.WebControls.Xml`, and `System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button`). And I can't find a way to get into the controls inside the XXML object/control so I can get the `SelectedValue` of the DropdownLists/options. How will I be able to access the controls inside the Xml1 object/control??

**Update 2: Here is the generated HTML code**:

```
<body>
    <form method="post" action="Main.aspx" id="form1">
      <div class="aspNetHidden">
        <input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE"     value="/wEPDwULLTE2MTY2ODcyMjlkZCn80c6JtFOE8ISKTFArpEqY4qC8tA9LkNAs7gn6n6Zu" />
     </div>    
   <div class="aspNetHidden">    
      <input type="hidden" name="__EVENTVALIDATION" id="__EVENTVALIDATION" value="/wEWAgLm9oEzAqDAiY0LmVXxKZ8kddyJnX1LgEhJf4qGDJE14PdWmMUYC7LLAAk=" />
   </div>
   <div>
   </div>
   <table id="tbl1" runat="server" xmlns:asp="remove">    
     <tr>
       <td>BEHAVIOR</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>Stellar KPIs</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>    
       <td>Customer Demeanor at Start of call:</td>
       <td>
         <select id="ddl_3" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"    onchange="getvalue(this);">
           <option value="0">Select</option>
           <option value="A">                Audibly Happy</option>
           <option value="N">                Neutral</option>    
           <option value="I">                Irate</option>
           <option value="R">                At risk</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Customer Demeanor at End of call:</td>    
    <td>
      <select id="ddl_8" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" onchange="getvalue(this);">
        <option value="0">Select</option>
        <option value="A">                Audibly Happy</option>
        <option value="N">                Neutral</option>
        <option value="I">                Irate</option>    
        <option value="R">                At risk</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
```

**Update 3: here's the screenshot of the HTML code rendered:** [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fOVrh.jpg)

**Update 4: here's the XSLT file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:asp="remove" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template name="home" match="/">
        <table id="tbl1" runat="server">
            <xsl:for-each select="ProgramKPI/KPIs">
                <xsl:variable name="varKPI" select="KPI_ID"/>
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="Level = '1'">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="Attribute"/>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="Level = '2'">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="Attribute"/>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="Level = '3'">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="Attribute"/>
                            </td>
                            <xsl:variable name="ddl_name" select="concat('ddl_', KPI_ID)"/>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:element name="select">
                                    <xsl:attribute name="id"><xsl:value-of select="concat('ddl_', KPI_ID)"/></xsl:attribute>
                                    <xsl:attribute name="runat">server</xsl:attribute>
                                    <xsl:attribute name="AutoPostBack">true</xsl:attribute>
                                    <xsl:attribute name="onchange">getvalue(this);</xsl:attribute>
                                    <xsl:element name="option">
                                        <xsl:attribute name="value"><xsl:value-of select="0"/></xsl:attribute>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="'Select'"/>
                                    </xsl:element>
                                    <xsl:for-each select="//Parent_KPI[.=$varKPI]">
                                        <xsl:element name="option">
                                            <xsl:attribute name="value"><xsl:value-of select="preceding-sibling::AttributeCode"/></xsl:attribute>
                                            <xsl:value-of select="preceding-sibling::Attribute"/>
                                        </xsl:element>
                                    </xsl:for-each>
                                </xsl:element>
                                <!--<asp:DropDownList id="{concat('ddl_', KPI_ID)}" runat="server">
                        <asp:ListItem value="0">  Select  
                        </asp:ListItem>

                        <xsl:for-each select="//Parent_KPI[.=$varKPI]">
                          <asp:ListItem>
                            <xsl:attribute name="value">
                              <xsl:value-of select="preceding-sibling::AttributeCode"/>
                            </xsl:attribute>
                            <xsl:value-of select="preceding-sibling::Attribute"/>
                          </asp:ListItem>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                      </asp:DropDownList>-->
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </xsl:when>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Not about XSLT (you could generate that list by any other means) but dynamic generated controls. Retagging.

Comment: If you think a picture is necessary to explain yourself, you can use one of the free image hosting services (like [imgur](http://imgur.com/)) to upload the image, and just add a link to it in your question.

Comment: You don't need to remove the `<` `>`. Just select the block of XML and press the `{}` icon or Control-K.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try checking for child controls. Ideally you'd do this recursively but as a quick and dirty way:

```
private void btnSubmit_Click(Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (Control c in form1.Controls) 
    {            
        if (c.HasControls())
        {
            foreach (Control child in c)
            {
                //Access Child controls here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That being said I'm unsure of adding controls to the page via XML this way.

Also you may want to add the controls earlier in the page lifecycle possibly the onInit event and make sure to not add the controls again on postback.

**UPDATE: In light of John Sanders answer:**
you could go old school and use the request object to access values, not a .net but it should work. E.g:

```
string dropDownValue = Request.Form["yourDropDownID"];
```

**Update 2**
To Iterate through the values posted back you can do the following:

```
private void btnSubmit_Click(Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (string key in Request.Form.AllKeys)
    {
        Response.Write (string.Format("{0} => {1}<br />", key, request.Form[key]));
    }
}
```

However, to do this you will need to make sure that the rendered HTML has a name attribute for the form elements. Change your XSLT for the select element to the following:

```
<xsl:element name="select">
   <xsl:attribute name="id">
      <xsl:value-of select="concat('ddl_', KPI_ID)"/>
   </xsl:attribute>
   <xsl:attribute name="name">
      <xsl:value-of select="concat('ddl_', KPI_ID)"/>
   </xsl:attribute>
   <xsl:attribute name="onchange">getvalue(this);</xsl:attribute>
   <xsl:element name="option">
      <xsl:attribute name="value">
         <xsl:value-of select="0"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:value-of select="'Select'"/>
</xsl:element>
```

Note the inclusion of the name attribute and the removal of the runat server and auto postback attributes.

Comment: @John P : when you said I "could go old school and use the request object to access values, not a .net..." does it mean I have to enter the code `string dropDownValue = Request.Form["yourDropDownID"];` in javascript?

Comment: @Rome, this code would still go in your btnSubmit_Click handler server side. The "yourDropDownID" is the ID rendered into the HTML control. This method uses the HTTP Request that is posted back to the server. You could also iterate through the request.form object, I'll see if I can get some code for this into my answer. By old school, I was meaning refering how this use to be done in classic asp, prior to .net.

Comment: @John P : oh, please do. I appreciate it. :) In response to your previous answer, I tried that `c.HasControls()` but it can't see the child controls inside the XML object/control.

Comment: @John P: thanks for Update 2. I tried it and this is what shows up on the page after clicking the Submit button:
`__VIEWSTATE => /wEPDwULLTE2MTY2ODcyMjlkZCn80c6JtFOE8ISKTFArpEqY4qC8tA9LkNAs7gn6n6Zu
__EVENTVALIDATION => /wEWAgLm9oEzAqDAiY0LmVXxKZ8kddyJnX1LgEhJf4qGDJE14PdWmMUYC7LLAAk=
ctl03 => Submit` is this correct? Do I need to do any other special thing to get the values from the ViewState?

Comment: Can you edit your question to include and example of the rendered HTML? That will help.

Comment: You won't be able to retrieve values from the viewsate in this way and you shouldn't need to. First check you can get a value using string val = Request.Form["ddl_3"]. Also check the rendered html to ensure there is one set of form tags on the page and that the dropdownlists are enclosed by t hem

Comment: @John P: thank you for the latest reply. I tried using 
`string val = Request.Form["ddl_3"];
Response.Write("value :" + val);` but it does not show any value. It only shows `value :` It also checked the rendered html and there is only one set of form tag on the page and the dropdownlists(select) are within that form tag.

Comment: Added more info, I forgot that the HTTP request uses a "name" attribute on the form elements. You'll need to update your XSLT based on me updated answer

Comment: @John P : "name" attribute? are you referring to the "name" attribute on the template tag? please check my Update 4 for the XSLT file.

Comment: I mean the dropdown list itself needs a name attribute. I've updated my answer to further explain what I mean. As a really rough guide given <select id="foo" name="foo"> the id attribute is used client side by javascript etc and the name attribute is used in the HTTP request by ASP, ASP.net, PHP etc

Comment: @John P : oohhh! that's it! Thank you so much sir for being so patient with me! It now worked! *sniff sniff* :'( Thank you sooo much and sorry that I'm totally noob. :')

Comment: No problem. We were all totally N00b once. An upvote when you get the rep would be nice though :-)

Answer (score 3):

This won't work.

Text like `<asp:DropDownList/>` need to be interpreted by ASP.NET in order to be treated as controls. You're just sending that text to the browser.

Answer (score 0):

You say that the XML and transform produce a list of dropdown lists - are they plain html tags, or does it create asp.net controls?

I seem to remember that you can only access controls from code-behind if they have an ID property and runat="server" set in the tag.

If they are plain html, can you influence the transform so that it includes an ID and runat="server" when it is applied to the xml, or is the transform out of your control?

Comment: They are not plain html tags. I created the controls using XSLT. 

`<xsl:element name="select"> 
<xsl:attribute name="id"> 
<xsl:value-of select="concat('ddl_', KPI_ID)"/> 
</xsl:attribute> 
<xsl:attribute name="runat">server
</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:element>`

Comment: the controls I have created have the "runat=server" attributes in them.